# Select the first result after name search in linked in in python

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to search a name in linked in and then select the first result, I have done almost everything except selecting the first result, I am unable to do that, i have tried with xpath(its only working for the profile u copy xpath not for different profile), but its not working, below is the code what I have tried. For now I am trying for only one profile, but it should work for many profiles. So I need a better solution. Please help.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'your chromedriver path\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("linked_in sign in page url")
username = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session_key']")))
password = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='session_password']")))

# enter username and password
username.clear()
username.send_keys("give your user name")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("your password")

# target the login button and click it for login
button = WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[type='submit']"))).click()

# find the search bar and enter name for search
search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[placeholder='Search']")))
search.clear()
search.send_keys("name of person")
search.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

# select the first result after search
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="main"]/div/div/div[1]/div/a/div'))).click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of that crazy xpath, it works quite well for me to simply use the following:  $$('a.app-aware-link')

```
WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.app-aware-link'))).click()
```

Comment: I have added that line, but its not working, do I need to paste the same line which u have given oro I need to change something?

Comment: After typing the name in the search bar, it comes back to home page, what should I do ? @C. Peck

Comment: The above should work, but obviously not if you are on the home page. What I might guess is that linkedin is detecting that you're using automation, which is a whole new can of worms...

Comment: Hi @C. Peck so in your case, you are also getting your home page first and then by entering a name u are clicking the first result, so it's working in your system.?

Comment: Hi C. Peck I just wanted to ask, can we connect in linked in , so if I have question posted in SO I may send the link to you to answer. Sorry if I violate any rules by adding this comment , I will delete it if u say.